# How to add boot.scr with Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, u-boot

I have a Yocto project from a distributor, which already appends to u-boot-imx with `u-boot-imx_%.bbappend`. For this project I want to add further u-boot environment variables. However, I do not want to adjust the `bbappend` from the distributor and I also do not want to replace it as it might change in the future.

As matter of fact I want to add a `boot.scr` file and add it to the created image, so that my changes to the environment are done during the boot process. The u-boot-inital-env created during the build includes already the line `script=boot.scr`. My question now is, how do I add the `boot.scr` file during the Yocto build?

The `uboot-config.bbclass`states the following:

```
# Additional environment variables or a script can be installed alongside
# u-boot to be used automatically on boot.  This file, typically 'uEnv.txt'
# or 'boot.scr', should be packaged along with u-boot as well as placed in the
# deploy directory.  Machine configurations needing one of these files should
# include it in the SRC_URI and set the UBOOT_ENV parameter.
```

Is it possible to create an additional append or patch, which packs the file with u-boot and places it also in the deploy directory?

Comment: You can have multiple `.bbappend` files for the same recipe, there is no limit on that. They will be applied after each other.

Comment: Okay, so you suggest to create a second .bbappend, which has a higher layer priority than the layer of the distributor, where the first .bbappend is located?

Comment: You can do that, or for example you could add a `do_configure:prepend()` task, where you simply overwrite the upstream `boot.scr` file. Your bbappend could have `my_boot.scr` file, and the `do_configure` step just do something like `mv my_boot.scr boot.scr`